Whenever I refresh the browser same user showing twice to others who refresh browser
I'm making Zoom Clone using Node.js peer.js.I write server side and client side code for this.In starting when users connected it shows each user only once but whenever I refresh the code is shows the user who refresh the code twice and if other person refresh then on onthers screen that user video showing twice.
Here is the image
starting(without refresing)

After refreshing on gwtear(random name) side [screen of other user(uifhjaekh)]

This is server side code

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("join-room", (roomId, id, myname) => {
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.to(roomId).emit("user-connected", id, myname);

    socket.on("messagesend", (message) => {
      console.log(message);
      io.to(roomId).emit("createMessage", message);
    });

    socket.on("tellName", (myname) => {
      console.log(myname);
      socket.to(roomId).emit("AddName", myname);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      socket.to(roomId).emit("user-disconnected", id);
    });
  });
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});

This is client side code
const socket = io("/");
const main__chat__window = document.getElementById("main__chat_window");
const videoGrids = document.getElementById("video-grids");
const myVideo = document.createElement("video");
const chat = document.getElementById("chat");
const screenShareButt = document.querySelector(".screenshare");

OtherUsername = "";
chat.hidden = true;
myVideo.muted = true;

var peer = new Peer(undefined, {
  path: "/peerjs",
  host: "/",
  port: "3000"
});

const connectedUsers = new Set();
let screenShare=false;
let myVideoStream;
const callList = [];
const peers = {};
var getUserMedia =
  navigator.getUserMedia ||
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
  navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

sendmessage = (text) => {
  if (event.key === "Enter" && text.value != "") {
    socket.emit("messagesend", myname + " : " + text.value);
    text.value = "";
    main__chat_window.scrollTop = main__chat_window.scrollHeight;
  }
};
function addUser(userId) {
  connectedUsers.add(userId);
}

// Remove a user from the set
function removeUser(userId) {
  connectedUsers.delete(userId);
}

navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    myVideoStream = stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream, myname);
    socket.on("user-connected", (id, username) => {
      console.log("userid:" + id);
      if(!connectedUsers.has(id)){
      connectToNewUser(id, stream, username);
      socket.emit("tellName", myname);
      addUser(id);}
    });
    socket.on("user-disconnected", (id) => {
      console.log(peers);
      if (peers[id]) peers[id].close();
      removeUser(id);
    });
  });

peer.on("call", (call) => {
  getUserMedia(
    { video: true, audio: true },
    function (stream) {
      call.answer(stream); 
      const video = document.createElement("video");
      call.on("stream", function (remoteStream) {
        addVideoStream(video, remoteStream, OtherUsername);
      });
    },
    function (err) {
      console.log("Failed to get local stream", err);
    }
  );
});

peer.on("open", (id) => {
  socket.emit("join-room", roomId, id, myname);
});

socket.on("createMessage", (message) => {
  var ul = document.getElementById("messageadd");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.className = "message";
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
  ul.appendChild(li);
});

socket.on("AddName", (username) => {
  OtherUsername = username;
  console.log(username);
});

const RemoveUnusedDivs = () => {
  //
  alldivs = videoGrids.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var i = 0; i < alldivs.length; i++) {
    e = alldivs[i].getElementsByTagName("video").length;
    if (e == 0) {
      alldivs[i].remove();
    }
  }
};

const connectToNewUser = (userId, streams, myname) => {
  const call = peer.call(userId, streams);
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
    //       console.log(userVideoStream);
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream, myname);
  });

  call.on("close", () => {
    video.remove();
    RemoveUnusedDivs();
  });
  peers[userId] = call;
};

const cancel = () => {
  $("#getCodeModal").modal("hide");
};

const copy = async () => {
  const roomid = document.getElementById("roomid").innerText;
  await navigator.clipboard.writeText("http://localhost:3000/join/" + roomid);
  $("#getCodeModal").modal("hide");
};

const invitebox = () => {
  $("#getCodeModal").modal("show");
};

const muteUnmute = () => {
  const enabled = myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled;
  if (enabled) {
    myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
    setUnmuteButton();
  } else {
    setMuteButton();
    myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true;
  }
};
const setMuteButton = () => {
  const html = `
      <i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>
      <span>Mute</span>
    `;
  document.querySelector(".main__mute_button").innerHTML = html;
};

const setUnmuteButton = () => {
  const html = `
      <i class="unmute fas fa-microphone-slash"></i>
      <span>Unmute</span>
    `;
  document.querySelector(".main__mute_button").innerHTML = html;
};

const VideomuteUnmute = () => {
  const enabled = myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled;
  console.log(getUserMedia);
  if (enabled) {
    myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;
    setPlayVideo();
  } else {
    setStopVideo();
    myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true;
  }
};

const setStopVideo = () => {
  const html = `
      <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
      <span>Stop Video</span>
    `;
  document.querySelector(".main__video_button").innerHTML = html;
};

const setPlayVideo = () => {
  const html = `
    <i class="stop fas fa-video-slash"></i>
      <span>Play Video</span>
    `;
  document.querySelector(".main__video_button").innerHTML = html;
};

const showchat = () => {
  if (chat.hidden == false) {
    chat.hidden = true;
  } else {
    chat.hidden = false;
  }
};

let screenOn=false;
// screen share
screenShareButt.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if(!screenOn){
    screenOn=true;
  screenshare();
}
else{screenOn=fale; stopscreenshare();}
});
function stopscreenshare(){
  getUserMediaAndConnect();
}

function screenshare() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: false
  }).then(stream => {
    myVideoStream = stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream, myname);
    socket.on("user-connected", (id, username) => {
      console.log("userid:" + id);
      connectToNewUser(id, stream, username);
      socket.emit("tellName", myname);
    });
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error accessing screen capture:', error);
  });
}


function adjustVideoSizes() {
  let totalUsers = document.getElementsByTagName("video").length;
  if (totalUsers > 1) {
    const videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    for (let index = 0; index < totalUsers; index++) {
      videos[index].style.width = 100 / totalUsers + "%";
    }
  }
}


// video grid adding 
const addVideoStream = (videoEl, stream, name) => {
  videoEl.srcObject = stream;
  videoEl.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    videoEl.play();
  });
  const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  const h1name = document.createTextNode(name);
  h1.appendChild(h1name);
  const videoGrid = document.createElement("div");
  videoGrid.classList.add("video-grid");
  videoGrid.appendChild(h1);
  videoGrids.appendChild(videoGrid);
  videoGrid.append(videoEl);
  RemoveUnusedDivs();
  adjustVideoSizes();
};

I'm expecting that whenever I refresh browser video should  shows only once not twice.
